# Adding Total Weight for both simple and variable product In woodmart mini cart widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woodmart theme and on mini cart widget and I want to show total weight and total price of simple and variable product.
So I have modified the code but it is not working and has these problem below:

**1. (Total weight):** when a simple or variable product added to cart the **total weight** is shown half of the product weight. For example if the product weight set to 0.5 , when added to cart , on mini cart the total weight is shown 0.25.

**2. (Total Price):** when a simple or variable product added to cart the **total price** is shown half of the product price. For example if the product price based on weight (0.5) is 7500,  when added to cart , on mini cart the total price is shown 3750.

[image: minicart.png]

Any help is appreciated. So many thanks.
Here is my code:

```
/* Display the total weight in the mini cart shopping cart widget footer*/
function display_mini_cart_total_weight() {
    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        $total_weight = 0;

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $product = $cart_item['data'];
            $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
            $weight = 0;

            if ( $variation_id ) {
                // Get the selected variation
                $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );

                if ( $variation ) {
                    // Get the weight of the variation
                    $weight = $variation->get_weight();
                }
            } else {
                // Get the weight of the product
                $weight = $product->get_weight();
            }

            $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];

            // Calculate the weight for the current product
            $product_weight = $weight * $quantity;

            // Add the product's weight to the total weight
            $total_weight += $product_weight;
        }

        // Output the total weight in the mini cart shopping cart widget footer
        $total_weight_display = $total_weight . ' Kg'; // Append ' Kg' to the total weight
        
        echo '<tr class="total-weight-row">
                <td colspan="3" class="total-weight-cell">
                    <p class="total-weight-label woocommerce-mini-cart__total">' . __('Total Weight:', 'chahar-4-rahewordpress') . '</p>
                    <p class="total-weight-value woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . $total_weight_display . '</p>
                </td>
            </tr>';
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons', 'display_mini_cart_total_weight' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the quantity is less than 1 then you have to consider min qty as 1. Check the below code.

```
/* Display the total weight and price in the mini cart shopping cart widget footer */
function display_mini_cart_total_weight() {
    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        $total_weight = 0;
        $total_price = 0;

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $weight = 0;
            $price = 0;
            $product = $cart_item['data'];
            $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];

            if ( $variation_id ) {
                // Get the selected variation
                $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );

                if ( $variation ) {
                    // Get the weight and price of the variation
                    $weight = $variation->get_weight();
                    $price = $variation->get_price();
                }
            } else {
                // Get the weight and price of the product
                $weight = $product->get_weight();
                $price = $product->get_price();
            }

            $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];

            if( $quantity < 1 ){
                $quantity = 1;
            }

            // Calculate the weight and price of the current product
            $product_weight = $weight * $quantity;
            $product_price = $price * $quantity;

            // Add the product's weight and price to the total weight and price
            $total_weight += $product_weight;
            $total_price += $product_price;
        }

        // Output the total weight and price in the mini cart shopping cart widget footer
        $total_weight_display = $total_weight . ' Kg'; // Append ' Kg' to the total weight
        $total_price_display = wc_price( $total_price ); // Format the total price as WooCommerce price

        echo '<tr class="total-weight-row">
                <td colspan="3" class="total-weight-cell">
                    <p class="total-weight-label woocommerce-mini-cart__total">' . __('Total Weight:', 'chahar-4-rahewordpress') . '</p>
                    <p class="total-weight-value woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . $total_weight_display . '</p>
                </td>
            </tr>';

        echo '<tr class="total-price-row">
                <td colspan="3" class="total-price-cell">
                    <p class="total-price-label woocommerce-mini-cart__total">' . __('Total Price 1:', 'chahar-4-rahewordpress') . '</p>
                    <p class="total-price-value woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . $total_price_display . '</p>
                </td>
            </tr>';
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons', 'display_mini_cart_total_weight' );
```

Comment: this code is working but is does not work based on woodmart theme total price. Please see this screesnshot:
https://i.postimg.cc/BvH191Xq/minicart02.png

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since many of your recent *twenty* answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.